# GAE Python Optimize Datastore Read Operations Quota Exceede

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached, google-cloud-datastore

I have designed a very simple app using python on GAE. It uses google data store.

In my apps I read from data store in this way:

```
user_db = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Names WHERE name=:1", key) 
user = user_db.get()
```

Store data in datasotre in this way:

```
class Names(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    id = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    result = db.StringProperty(required=True)
e = Names(name=key,id=23,result=test)
```

But unfortunately my account's Datastore Read Operations quota got exceeded within and hour.

I heard something about memcache. So I wanna know how can I optimize these read/write operations using mem cache?

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent intro guide to memcache [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/usingmemcache).

When you need a chunk of data, you try to find it in the memcache.  If it's not there, you do your normal db lookup, and stash the result in the memcache for later use.  Memcache follows a "Least Recently Used" (LRU) eviction policy.  This means that when you go to add an entry and the cache has reached your storage limits, the entry that has remained untouched the longest is deleted.

Quoting from that document:

Memcache is typically used with the following pattern:

- The application receives a query from the user or the application.
- The application checks whether the data needed to satisfy that query is in memcache.

  - If the data is in memcache, the application uses that data.
  - If the data is not in memcache, the application queries the datastore and stores the results in memcache for future requests.

The pseudocode below represents a typical memcache request:

```
def get_data():
    data = memcache.get('key')
    if data is not None:
        return data
    else:
        data = self.query_for_data()
        memcache.add('key', data, 60)
        return data
```